# Manipulating user input from tkinter text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, user-input

I have coded a basic GUI with tkinter - see below code. I have it at the point where the user can copy/paste into the "Customer Description" and it will create a list of the items. I figured what I was trying to do would make more sense if the user input was in list format.

Example of user input:

1. PIPE, 12", SA-106 GR. B, SCH 40, 0.406" WALL SMLS
2. PIPE, 8", SA-106 GR. B, SCH 40, 0.322" WALL SMLS
3. PIPE, 6", SA-106 GR. C, SCH 160, 0.719" WALL SMLS
4. ELBOW 45 LR, 16", SA-234 WPB, SCH 40, 0.500" WALL, BW SMLS

Now that I have the user input, I need to run my python program for every entry and have it inserted into the 2nd text field titled "dave_description".

My question is what is the best way to have the function do that? I can't seem to figure out how to have it run the function for each entry but I also need to have it populate the 2nd text box. I figured out how to have the original text "insert" into it but no idea how to do that now that I've turned it into a list.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import BOTH, END, LEFT

HEIGHT = 970
WIDTH = 1500

root = tk.Tk()
root.title( 'Daves Generator')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='david.png')
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame_one = tk.Frame(root, bg='#003d70',bd=5)
frame_one.place(relx=0.17, rely=.15, relwidth=0.3,relheight=0.8, anchor='n')

customer_description = tk.Text(frame_one, state=NORMAL, width=125, wrap=WORD, height=500,font=("Courier", 8))
customer_description.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame_two = tk.Frame(root, bg='#003d70',bd=5)
frame_two.place(relx=0.5, rely=.15, relwidth=0.3,relheight=0.8, anchor='n')

dave_description = tk.Text(frame_two, width=125, height=500,font=("Courier", 8))
dave_description.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame_three = tk.Frame(root, bg='#003d70',bd=5)
frame_three.place(relx=0.83, rely=.15, relwidth=0.3,relheight=0.8, anchor='n')

sap_code = tk.Label(frame_three, width=125, height=500,font=("Courier", 8))
sap_code.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

header_frame_one = tk.Label(root, text="Customer Descriptions", font=("Courier", 14), fg='#003d70')
header_frame_one.place(relx=0.17, rely=0.13, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.025, anchor='n')

header_frame_two = tk.Label(root, text="PJ Descriptions", font=("Courier", 14), fg='#003d70')
header_frame_two.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.13, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.025, anchor='n')

header_frame_three = tk.Label(root, text="SAP Code", font=("Courier", 14), fg='#003d70')
header_frame_three.place(relx=0.83, rely=0.13, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.025, anchor='n')

generate_button = tk.Button(root,text="Generate!", font=("Courier", 14), fg='white', bg='#003d70', command=lambda: get_customer_description())
generate_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.08, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.025, anchor='n')

def get_customer_description():
    all_descriptions = [customer_description.get("1.0", "end-1c")]
    print(all_descriptions)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: does [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm) help? there are methods amongst whom `insert` is mentioned somewhere at the bottom.

Comment: @Matiiss I used that reference to learn how to build the basic GUI and did some .insert testing to see how it then displays a value back to user. I suppose I am asking now that I have gotten the multiline text with .get, how can I run my function on each line individually?

Comment: split the input by newline like this `user_input = user_input.split('n')`, this will return a list which should have each line seperately

Comment: @Matiiss My current setup that includes ```[...]``` around my ```.get``` as shown here```all_descriptions = [customer_description.get("1.0", "end-1c")]``` provides the result of ```['1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n\n']```. When I add your solution in addition to the list brackets, it returns ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'```. When I remove the ```[...]```, it gives me ```['1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n']``` Is that in list a list format? I don't know how to access that to run my function on the retrieved data if it is.

Comment: there is no point for this `all_descriptions = [customer_description.get("1.0", "end-1c")]` (for the brackets). this should work instead: `all_descriptions = customer_description.get("1.0", "end-1c").split('\n')`. then You have to iterate through each of the items in that list using `for` loop

Comment: That will do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Matiiss!! Posting the answer so it shows as resolved. If you would post it so I can accept your answer and upvote it!

```
result= text_widget.get("1.0", "end-1c").split("\n")
    for line in result:
        func_1():
```